# Using Scikit RandomizedPCA Python

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, pca, face-recognition

I'm programming in Python 3.4 and I'm trying to use a package form scikit called RandomizedPCA in my program to recognize persons in photos.

```
from sklearn.decomposition import RandomizedPCA

n_components = 150

print ("Extracting the top %d eigenfaces from %d faces" % (n_components, X_train.shape[0]))
pca = RandomizedPCA(n_components = n_components, whiten=True)

#%time pca.fit(X_train)

eigenfaces = pca.components_.reshape((n_components, h, w))
```

But when I run it returns this:

```
AttributeError: 'RandomizedPCA' object has no attribute 'components_'
```

Comment: You can only access `pca.components_` after calling the `pca.fit()` method. Does this error occur when you add the `pca.fit(X_train)` line?